# LoadBlockIndexDB: transaction index disabled

Tags: bitcoind, raspberry-pi, reindex, txindex

I'm trying to run bitcoind on a Raspberry Pi 3 but I'm stuck on an error. The raspberry has a Hdd for storage with a fully indexed blockchain that was synced on my laptop and than copied to the Hdd (txindex=1).

When calling the log file I get this message:

[image]

Side note: I also did a reindex-chainstate=1 afterwords, but I still got this issue.

Comment: why does it say transaction index disabled? are you using `-txindex` on the pi?

Comment: I have no idea. Yes, it runs with `txindex=1`

Comment: which version of `bitcoind` is the pi running?

Comment: Version 0.16.3. I followed these steps for LND ==> https://github.com/Stadicus/guides/blob/master/raspibolt/raspibolt_30_bitcoin.md

Answer (score 0):

`transaction index disabled` is logged when the `txindex=1` or `-txindex` flag is not set. If it was once indexed, and you don't pass that flag, then bitcoind will prevent you from accidentally rebuilding the database without the indexes unless you explicitly tell it to with `-reindex`. Check your `bitcoin.conf` file and the startup script. Alternatively, try adding `-txindex` to `/etc/systemd/system/bitcoind.service` where `bitcoind` is called:

`ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/bitcoind -txindex -daemon -conf=/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf -pid=/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/bitcoind.pid`

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it didn't solved it. When calling this command I get: `Bitcoin server starting`. But when calling the debug file, it still gives "LoadBlockIndexDB: transaction index disabled". Could it be something with RPC connections because this also doesn't work when calling for `bitcoin-cli' commands

Comment: I don't think it is running at all anymore (it says Exiting), you can check with `ps | aux grep bitcoind`, so RPC commands won't work either.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me "admin     7651  0.0  0.0   4372   568 pts/0    S+   16:32   0:00 grep --color=auto bitcoind".  
     When asking for the command `systemctl status bitcoind.service`, I get a green message `Active (running)`. So I assume it's running?

Comment: Did you try restarting the service? `sudo systemctl restart bitcoind.service`? You can try running it directly (not as a service) until you get it working. `bitcoind -txindex -daemon`

Comment: Also this gives me the same error as above. I can't get my head around, because the same blockchain (same bitcoin folder with index and chainstate) works perfectly on my laptop with the UI. Do you think, it has something to do with the RPC credentials?

Comment: No, I don't think so. If you copied the entire .bitcoin folder over, and run the same version of `bitcoind` with `txindex` flag, it *should* work, unless I'm missing something